# Python eigenvectors

Tags: python, eigenvector

```
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = linalg.eig(K)
```

How can I print just eigenvectors of `len(K)`. So if there is `K`, 2x2 matrix, I get 4 eigenvectors, how can I print just 2 of them if there is `len(K)=2`....

Many thanks

Comment: why not `print eigenvectors[:len(K)]` ?

Comment: This matrix K is not always 2x2....it's random 4x4,....

Comment: Also I can add, print eigenvectors[:len(K)], this will not work  if there is just 2x2 matrix, it print's 4 elements, not just 2....

Comment: @thaking: Four vectors? You are probably getting two vectors each of length two (four numbers in total). Can you show the exact matrix you're passing to `eig` and the exact results you're getting back.

Comment: Yes 2 vectors length two; 4 numbers TOTAL;  I only need on vector, if there is K 2x2;

Comment: how can you get 4 eigenvectors from 2x2 matrix???

Comment: @thaking Slow down cowboy. You don't understand eigenvectors. Head back to your maths text books before proceeding.

Comment: Ok, it seems like I didn't get it. I thought you should write `print eigenvectors[: eigenvalues.index(<index of first almost zero eigenvalue>)]`

Comment: I misunderstood something in my code, so i was little confused,sorry, I solved my problem now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are getting two vectors of length two, not four vectors. For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: K=np.random.normal(size=(2,2))

In [3]: eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(K)

In [4]: eigenvectors
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0.83022467+0.j        ,  0.83022467+0.j        ],
       [ 0.09133956+0.54989461j,  0.09133956-0.54989461j]])

In [5]: eigenvectors.shape
Out[5]: (2, 2)
```

The first vector is `eigenvectors[:,0]`, the second is `eigenvectors[:,1]`.

Comment: Yes, but how to print just 1 vector ?

Comment: Thanks I misunderstood something in my code, so i was little confused, thanks.

Comment: eigenvectors are columns, not rows;

Answer (score 0):

From the manual:

> The normalized eigenvector
>   corresponding to the eigenvalue `w[i]`
>   is the column `v[:,i]`.