# How to obtain standard deviation and proportion of variance from eigenvector eigenvalues

Tags: python, variance, eigenvector

How to obtain standard deviation and proportion of variance from eigenvector eigenvalues ? Il like to implement the calculation in Python.

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is centered to programming related Q&A style of questions - not giving basic lectures that you can reasaearch using google or math pages around the web. Do you have a specific, programming related question on code you can provide? If not, search SO for similar requests like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953297/python-eigenvectors - nobody here is going to give you basic teachings about how to calculate those, thats not what SO is about. Try https://math.stackexchange.com/ - BUT read theire tour and how-to-asks first and search before you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy way to calculate the relative contribution of each eigenvalue/vector in your data using sklearn in python.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(X)
```

the pca object has an attribute called explained variance, which shows the proportion of variance from each eigenvector.

```
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
```

See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html for more details.